# Separability in Algebra and Topology

Tags: general-topology, notation, meta-math

I am wondering about the use of the word separablity in two different areas of mathematics, namely algebra and topology.

In topology, we call a topological space $(X,\mathscr{T})$ if it contains a dense subset, $\bar{D}=X$, with $d(X)$≤$\omega$ (with $|\mathbb{N}|=\omega$).

In algebra, I heard of separable polynomials $p \in K[X]$, $K$ being a field, meaning that the roots of those polynomials are all distinct in the algebraic closure $\bar{K}$, using the bar notation here too.

I cannot connect those two concepts. 
Therefore my question to you is:

**Can you think of an example putting together the concept of polynomials, density and continouity and closure in order to connect those two different kinds of separablity or can you show me why it is not a good question to ask?**

In particular I am wondering if one can use $\sigma$-finiteness (which in a way has some properties in common with separablity - the sets wont get too big, stay countable). So I'd be fine with something using $\sigma$-finiteness and measureability too (where separablity is used for Lusin's theorem as a condition that says that measureablity is at least close to continouity).

Comment: Maybe you can; I can't say. I can say that you should try to get used to notation overload in mathematics. Normal subgroups and normal topological spaces have nothing to do with each other, for instance. (I would bet that these are distinct concepts, too.)

Comment: Hello Mike. Thank you for your comment. I do understand your point about the notation overload but I mostly think that this is only valid for non-descriptive terms like normal or regular. Separable is, at least for me, a bit more specific than just normal.